# Calling mysql queries dependent on another query in node

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequential

can anyone help me.
I need to get result of queryA [which is an update query that returns ROW_COUNT( )], see if the result is equal to 1.
If not, just return it via res.json
If yes, call queryB [which returns a set of rows].

After which, I have to loop and call queryC to update each row. It has to be one at a time because the queryC is also inserting auditTrails within the stored procedure.

This is the source code:

```js
exports.migrateCustomer = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { oldCustomerID, newCustomerID, userID } = req.body;
    const connection = mysql.createConnection(config);
    let sql = `CALL usp_UpdateCustomerCallStatusIdAndIsActive(?,?,?)`;
    /*UPDATE Customer*/
    const updateCus = connection.query(sql, [oldCustomerID, 'Duplicate', userID], (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.error(error.message);
        }
        return results[0];
    });

    if (updateCus.rowCount == 1) {
        let sql = `CALL usp_GetPurchaseOrderByCustomerIDAndNameSearch(?,?)`;
        /*GET rows to be updated*/
        const GetRows = connection.query(sql, [oldCustomerID, ''], (error, results, fields) => {
            if (error) {
                return console.error(error.message);
            }
            results[0].forEach(element => {
                let sql = `CALL usp_UpdatePurchaseOrderByCustomerID(?,?)`;
                /*UPDATE rows*/
                connection.query(sql, [newCustomerID, userID], (error, results, fields) => {
                    if (error) {
                        return console.error(error.message);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }

    res.json(updateCus);

    connection.end();
});
```

Error:
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'Query'

then another one at the bottom:
throw er; //Unhandled 'error' event

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 'await' before the mysql.createConnection(config)  and connection.query call, since these are asynchronous functions. Also in your code connection.end() should be inside the callback.

```
exports.migrateCustomer = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
   const { oldCustomerID, newCustomerID, userID } = req.body;
   const connection = await mysql.createConnection(config);
   let sql = `CALL usp_UpdateCustomerCallStatusIdAndIsActive(?,?,?)`;
   /*UPDATE Customer*/
   const updateCus = await connection.query(sql, [oldCustomerID, 'Duplicate', userID], (error, results, fields) => {
       if (error) {
           connection.end();
           return console.error(error.message);
       }
        return results[0];
        });
           
       
       if (updateCus.rowCount == 1) {
       let sql = `CALL usp_GetPurchaseOrderByCustomerIDAndNameSearch(?,?)`;
       /*UPDATE Customer*/
       connection.query(sql, [oldCustomerID, ''], (error, results, fields) => {
           if (error) {
           connection.end();
               return console.error(error.message);
           }
           results[0].forEach(element => {
               let sql = `CALL usp_UpdatePurchaseOrderByCustomerID(?,?)`;
               /*UPDATE Customer*/
               connection.query(sql, [newCustomerID, userID], (error, results, fields) => {
               connection.end();
                   if (error) {
                        return console.error(error.message);
                   }
               });
           });
       });
   }else{
   connection.end();
   return res.status(200).json({
         customer:updateCus});
   }
   
});
```